# Values updating automatically inside the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

I was trying to implement the value iteration algorithm.
I have a grid

```
grid = [[0, 0, 0, +1],
    [0, "W", 0, -1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

An actionlist

```
actlist = {UP:1, DOWN:2, LEFT:3, RIGHT:4}
```

And a reward function

```
reward = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0,  0]]
```

I wrote a function T, which returns tuple of 3 tuples.

```
def T(i,j,actions):
if(i == 0 and j == 0):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i,i,0.8),(i,i,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i+1,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i+1,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j+1,0.8),(i,i,0.1),(i+1,j,0.1)
elif (i == 0 and j == 1):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i,i,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j-1,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j+1,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
elif(i == 0 and j == 2):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return(i+1,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j-1,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i+1,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j+1,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i+1,j,0.1)
elif(i == 0 and j == 3):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (-1,-1,0.8),(-1,-1,0.1),(-1,-1,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (-1,-1,0.8),(-1,-1,0.1),(-1,-1,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (-1,-1,0.8),(-1,-1,0.1),(-1,-1,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (-1,-1,0.8),(-1,-1,0.1),(-1,-1,0.1)
# 2nd row
elif (i == 1 and j == 0):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i-1,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i+1,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i+1,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i+1,j,0.1)
elif(i == 1 and j ==1):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
elif (i == 1 and j == 2):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i-1,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i+1,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i+1,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j+1,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i+1,j,0.1)
elif(i == 1 and j == 3):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (-2,-2,0.8),(-2,-2,0.1),(-2,-2,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (-2,-2,0.8),(-2,-2,0.1),(-2,-2,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (-2,-2,0.8),(-2,-2,0.1),(-2,-2,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (-2,-2,0.8),(-2,-2,0.1),(-2,-2,0.1)      
# 3rd row
elif(i == 2 and j == 0):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i-1,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j+1,1,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j+1,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
elif (i == 2 and j == 1):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j-1,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j+1,0.8),(i,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
elif(i == 2 and j == 2):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i-1,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j+1,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j-1,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i,j,1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j+1,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
elif(i == 2 and j == 3):
    if(actions == UP):
        return (i-1,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == DOWN):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i,j-1,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == LEFT):
        return (i,j-1,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
    elif(actions == RIGHT):
        return (i,j,0.8),(i-1,j,0.1),(i,j,0.1)
```

This function is called in the value iteration function:

```
def value_iteration():
U1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0]] 
while True:
    U=U1.copy()
    delta = 0
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            U1[i][j] = max(sum(p*(R(k,l)+gamma*U[k][l]) for (k,l,p) in T(i,j,a)) for a in actlist)
            print(i,j,U1[i][j],U[i][j])
            delta = max(delta, abs(U1[i][j] - U[i][j]))
    if delta <= epsilon*(1 - gamma)/gamma:
        return U
```

I was updating

```
U=U1.copy()
```

in the while loop.

The problem is, the output looks like this:

```
0 0 0.0 0.0
0 1 0.0 0.0
0 2 0.0 0.0
0 3 1.0 1.0
1 0 0.0 0.0
1 2 0.0 0.0
1 3 -1.0 -1.0
2 0 0.0 0.0
2 1 0.0 0.0
2 2 0.7000000000000001 0.7000000000000001
2 3 0.9630000000000001 0.9630000000000001
```

But I was not updating U inside the for loops. U was supposed to remain unchanged (that means, all zeros) and U1 was only supposed to change. Why U become automatically set to the value of U1 inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U1 (and U) is a list of lists, really a list of references to lists.

You're (shallow) copying the outer list, but the contents of the copy are still references to the same inner lists.

Try:

```
import copy
U = copy.deepcopy(U1)
```

and see what happens instead. `deepcopy` will correctly recursively copy the lists.

Comment: Thank you. But there is still a problem. Value of U1[2][2] and U1[2][3] was supposed to be zero. But they got updated to other values.

Answer (score 0):

nimish's answer is probably the most pythonic, but if you need to create a copy of a list, you can also just unpack it into a new array:

```
U = U1[:]
```

Which creates a new object that *shouldn't* reference the old one

```
mylist = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
otherlist= mylist[:]
otherlist[0] = [5,5,5]
mylist
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```